# Using the value of a variable for setting my load path

Tags: elisp

Okay, I'm a newb to modifying my .el files.
All I want to do is something like:
(setq windows-path "c:/Documents and Settings/cthiel/projects/windows_setup/emacs/")

And then tack on subdirectories within the emacs directory onto the load path.
Something such as (how it's done in ruby):
(add-to-list 'load-path "#{windows-path}/external")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq windows-path "c:/Documents and Settings/cthiel/projects/windows_setup/emacs/"
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat windows-path "external"))
```

Does that achieve your goal?

Documentation:

> concat is a built-in function in
>   `fns.c'.
>
> (concat &rest sequences)
>
> Concatenate all the arguments and make
>   the result a string. The result is a
>   string whose elements are the elements
>   of all the arguments. Each argument
>   may be a string or a list or vector of
>   characters (integers).

example:

```
(concat "The answer to life, " "the universe " "and everything " "is " "42")
  => "The answer to life, the universe and everything is 42"
```

Comment: Did the trick just fine, thanks! Knew it was something easy, just didn't know what. :}

Answer (score 2):

Check out [EmacsWiki:LoadPath](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/LoadPath) for tips on recursively adding directories.

I think you want something like:

```
(setq windows-path "c:/Documents and Settings/cthiel/projects/windows_setup/emacs/")

(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
    (let* ((my-lisp-dir windows-path)
           (default-directory my-lisp-dir))
      (setq load-path (cons my-lisp-dir load-path))
      (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)))
```